# Writing new line after variable in file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting, grep

I'm writing a script in bash and I'm using a tempfile to store some numbers I need. I receive a couple of numbers of a grep and want to write it into the file
with a new line after each number, except the last one.

```
myparts=$(grep -f parts.txt number.log | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}'| sort | uniq)
    echo -e $myparts+'\n' >> tempfile
```

This is what I tried and what didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` is not the string concatenation operator in shell.

```
echo -e "$myparts\n" >> tempfile
```

Comment: @acezcoder `echo "$myparts"` should get you each number on a line by itself. You are losing the inner whitespace inside `$myparts` when you fail to quote it.